# Which version of OSS do I download for drivers for my soundcard?

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

I'm running Ubuntu 64 bit 13.10, processor Intel® Core™2 CPU 6600 @ 2.40GHz × 2.
I have found a web-site which will supply me with drivers for my Audiophile 2496 PCI soundcard.
Which version do I download for my OSS?   The choice is as follows :-

Linux x86

```
Linux 2.4 (x86): For any Linux 2.4.xx kernel ether SMP or UniProcessor kernel (eg: Redhat, Mandrake, SuSE, Caldera, TurboLinux,   Debian, etc)
Linux 2.6 (x86): For any Linux 2.6.xx kernel ether SMP or UniProcessor kernel compiled without CONFIG_REGPARM. Only Mandrake 10 series requires this version.
Linux 2.6 (x86) (REGPARM): For any Linux 2.6.xx kernel ether SMP or UniProcessor kernel compiled with CONFIG_REGPARM=y. SuSE/Fedora Core3 and others require this version
Linux 2.2 (x86) (OLD) : For any Linux 2.2.x/2.4.x kernel running on x86 processor.
```

Linux amd64

```
Linux 2.6 (amd64): For any Linux 2.6.xx kernel ether SMP or UniProcessor kernel on AMD Athlon64/Opteron
```

Solaris

```
Solaris (x86): Solaris v7/v8/v9/v10 on Intel x86
Solaris (x86) (PCI-ONLY): PCI Bus ONLY version with support for all PCI cards
Solaris (sparc) 32bit : Solaris v7/v8/v9/v10 on PCI Bus based SPARC with 32bit kernel
Solaris (sparc) 64bit : Solaris v7/v8/v9 on PCI Bus based SPARC with 64bit kernel
```

All others

```
AIX 4: AIX 4.x/5.x on PowerPCs
BSD/OS 4.2: BSD/OS 4.2 for x86
FreeBSD 4.x: FreeBSD 4x RELEASE, for SMP systems, select the -SMP version.
FreeBSD 5.2.3: FreeBSD 5.2.1 RELEASE (both SMP/UP supported)
LynxOS 4: Lynx Real Time v4 x86
SCO OpenServer 5 : SCO OpenServer Release 5 for x86
OpenBSD 3.x: OpenBSD 3.x for x86
NetBSD 2.0: NetBSD 2.0 for x86
HPUX: HPUX 11 for PA-RISC machines with PCI slots
UnixWare 7: UnixWare 7 for x86
Tru64: Tru64 v5.x for Alpha processor
```

Any of the above/none of the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 64 bit 13.10  means you are using amd64 so this one:

```
Linux 2.6 (amd64): For any Linux 2.6.xx kernel ether SMP or UniProcessor kernel on AMD Athlon64/Opteron
```

would be my choise. The easiest method is to remember what the name of the ISO was that you downloaded. It will have amd64 or i386 (that would be the 1st group you listed) in the name.

By the way: solaris is a totally different platform. So are "all the others". General rule: 1st try ubuntu software center, next try to find a debian installer (.deb), next tar.gz marked as Linux i386 (32 bit) /amd64 (64 bit). And if that fails you might consider hunting down the source and compile yourself.